# How to write to existing Excel File (XLS)

Tags: python, robotframework

I am newbie. I try to write data in existing excel file. When I run on robotframework, it display "No keyword with name 'Write To Excel File' found". So could you help me to fix my code or give me suggestion to me?

```
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy

class Excel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "write to excel file"

    def group(self,lst, n):

         return ([lst[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(lst),n)])
    def write_to_excel_file(self,filename,content_list):

            # Existing Excel File
            w = copy(filename)
            b = w.get_sheet(0)

            # Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
            #workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
            #worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('wb')

            #content_lists=[1,1,'hello',2,1,'brother',3,1,'how are you',4,1,'are you good today']
            t=self.group(content_list,3)
            #print(t)
            for item in t:
                b.write(int(item[0]), int(item[1]), item[2])


            # close work book
                w.save(filename)
```

Comment: be careful you're calling `w.save(filename)` in the loop.

Comment: Suddenly what happened , yesterday you were able to call that :)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you

```
import xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd
import os.path

class Excel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "write to excel file"

    def group(self,lst, size):
        return ([lst[i:i+size] for i  in range(0, len(lst), size)])

    def write_to_excel_file(self,filename,content_list):
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            workbook = xlwt.Workbook() # Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
            worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('wb') #add worksheet
            workbook.save(filename)
        rb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename,formatting_info=True)
        r_sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0) 
        r = r_sheet.nrows
        wb = copy(rb) 
        sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
        t=self.group(content_list,3)
        for item in t:
            sheet.write(int(item[0]), int(item[1]), item[2])
        wb.save(filename)
```

RIDE test cases

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections
Library           WriteExcel.Excel

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
Write Excel Test first
    [Tags]
    @{content}    Create List
    Append To List    ${content}    15    1    Test Case 1
    Append To List    ${content}    16    1    Test Case 2
    Append To List    ${content}    17    1    Test Case 3
    Append To List    ${content}    18    1    Test Case 4
    Write To Excel File    test3.xls    ${content}
    log    @${content}

Write Excel Test Second
    [Tags]
    @{content}    Create List
    Append To List    ${content}    25    1    Test Case 11
    Append To List    ${content}    26    1    Test Case 12
    Append To List    ${content}    27    1    Test Case 13
    Append To List    ${content}    28    1    Test Case 14
    Write To Excel File    test3.xls    ${content}
    log    @${content}
```

Comment: @Shijo I have a problem when I use with ExcelLibrary. It display IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w+b') or filename: u'test3.xls'. Can you help me to solve this problem? 

*** Settings *** 
Library Collections 
Library WriteExcel.Excel 
Library ExcelLibrary 
*** Variables *** 
*** Test Cases *** 
Write Excel Test first 
Open Excel Current Directory test3.xls 
@{content} Create List 
Append To List ${content} 15 1 Test Case 1 
Write To Excel File test3.xls ${content} 
log @${content}

Comment: looks like your file may be open somewhere else. close that and try again

Comment: @Shijo Does it relate with Open Excel Current Directory?Because I think I already closed excel file.