# Failed to write to Excel files using the pd.ExcelWriter

Tags: python

This is my first post and I am not sure if I can paste the code generate from ChatGPT in my questions. I checked there're some posts asking they failed to achieve their goals using ChatGPT code, so I leave the complete code here for reference. But if that's not allowed, please kindly tell me and I will delete it.

My goal here is to:

1. I have a single xlsx with multiple sheets, and I want to modify three of them.
2. The data is about survey responses. For q11 and q12, the responses collected in online survey is in string variable [Very likely, Likely, Unlikely, Very Unlikely], and I wish to change each value in the two columns in [1, 2, 3, 4]
3. I want to modify the two columns in three dataframes together if possible. After that, I want to rewrite the numeric value into original excel file without changing the sheets' name.

And the code:

```
# Import the pandas library
import pandas as pd
!pip install openpyxl


# Read the Excel file into multiple pandas DataFrames, one for each sheet in the file
df1 = pd.read_excel('surveyresultlist.xlsx', sheet_name='psyc3740')
df2 = pd.read_excel('surveyresultlist.xlsx', sheet_name='gism5022')
df3 = pd.read_excel('surveyresultlist.xlsx', sheet_name='sutm5001')

# Create the response_map dictionary
response_map = {
    'Very likely': 1,
    'Likely': 2,
    'Unlikely': 3,
    'Very unlikely': 4,
}

# Create a writer object that can be used to write the updated dataframes to the original Excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('survey_responses.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# Iterate through the dataframes and convert the responses to numeric values
for df in [df1, df2, df3]:
    # Select the columns that contain the survey responses
    selected_columns = df[['q11', 'q12']]

    for i, response in selected_columns.iteritems():
        # Use the response_map dictionary to convert the response to a numerical value
        # Here, we access the actual response value using the `.iloc` attribute of the Series object
        numeric_response = response_map[response.iloc[0]]

        # Use the index to update the DataFrame with the numeric response
        df.at[i, response.index] = numeric_response

    # Write each updated dataframe to the original Excel file
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=df.index.name, index=False)

# Save the changes to the original Excel file
writer.save()
```

And the Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bf447073de77> in <module>
     34 
     35     # Write each updated dataframe to the original Excel file
---> 36     df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=df.index.name, index=False)
     37 
     38 # Save the changes to the original Excel file

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
   2187             inf_rep=inf_rep,
   2188         )
-> 2189         formatter.write(
   2190             excel_writer,
   2191             sheet_name=sheet_name,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
    819 
    820         try:
--> 821             writer.write_cells(
    822                 formatted_cells,
    823                 sheet_name,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in write_cells(self, cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes)
    392     ):
    393         # Write the frame cells using openpyxl.
--> 394         sheet_name = self._get_sheet_name(sheet_name)
    395 
    396         _style_cache: Dict[str, Dict[str, Serialisable]] = {}

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in _get_sheet_name(self, sheet_name)
    832             sheet_name = self.cur_sheet
    833         if sheet_name is None:  # pragma: no cover
--> 834             raise ValueError("Must pass explicit sheet_name or set cur_sheet property")
    835         return sheet_name
    836 

ValueError: Must pass explicit sheet_name or set cur_sheet property
```

What should I do? I am basially a newbie, so glad if you can explain with more detail. Many thanks!

I tried to input the error, ask ChatGPT where's the problem, understand ChatGPT's answer for numerous time. The answer always sounds convincing but the code is not working in any case. I wonder if I should not use Juptyer Notebook, but sincerely I have no idea what is the problem and how I can solve it.

I have tried to search the answer from the internet, like this one: [How to write to existing Excel File (XLS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875495/how-to-write-to-existing-excel-file-xls)   . But I have no idea what kind of code it is to be honest.

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Regarding ChatGPT, SO has a [strict policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy), which in my eyes aims at anwers, but as it is phrased even a question might be problematic...

Comment: If the question is (roughly) "this code from ChatGPT does not work and ChatGPT is not able to fix it, can you please fix it for me", then this is certainly not on-topic for Stack Overflow. As always, create a [mre], explain what you are trying to achieve, what the input, expected output and actual output are and provide debugging details. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Regarding "_The answer always sounds convincing but the code is not working in any case_".. That's **exactly** why ChatGPT is currently banned.

Comment: The question is now solved. I am sincerely sorry the reason is I made a typo in the excel value without notice. And therefore Python cannot convert the string based on the dictionary. Sorry for bothering you guys. So friendly here!

Answer (score 2):

You never set `df.index.name` do something meaningful, so it is `None`. This is also clear by inspecting the stacktrace. The exception is raised `if sheet_name is None`.

Explicitly set the index of each dataframe, either with `index_col` argument of `read_excel` (consult the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)) or with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

Comment: A stack trace is a list of the method calls that the application was in the middle of when an Exception was thrown? I will check and see how I can learn to inspect the stacktrace, thanks!

So in my case, what should I do to overwrite the value in sheets "psyc3740' 'gism5022' 'sutm5001'? Do I need to change the code completely or fixing a few lines of code will solve that problem?

Comment: In this instance you will need to explicitly set the index of each dataframe, either with `index_col` argument of `read_excel` (consult the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)) or with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)